# Why does this result in a can't assign to operator error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why "can't assign to operator" error for this line `point * hours = QP`?

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, name, surname, grade, hours, QP):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.grade = grade
        self.hours = hours
        self.QP = QP
    def getName(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)

    def getSurname(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.surname)

    def getGrade(self):
        return list(zip(self.grade, self.hours))

    def getHours(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.hours)
    def point(self):
        if grade == A:
            point = 4.0
        elif grade == B:
            point = 3.0
        elif grade == C:
            point = 2.0
        elif grade == D:
            point = 1.0
        else:
            point = 0.0

    def getQPoints(self):
        point * hours = QP
        return QP

    stud1 = Student("John","Brown",["A","B","A"],["15.0","25.0","20.0"],"")
    stud2 = Student("Mary","Watson",["C","A","B"],["15.0","25.0","20.0"],"")

    print (stud1.getQPoints())
```

Comment: Because `point * hours` is an [_rvalue_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)#lrvalue) and not an _lvalue_.

Comment: What do you *expect* that line to do?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yep, read the code fast pre-edit.

Comment: Try using `QP = point * hours` instead. In Python `=` is an assignment operator, not a mathematical "equals" sign. The destination (_lvalue_) goes to the left of the symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that you can reverse that. Instead, do

```
QP = point * hours
```

That way, you instantiate the new variable, and set it to the product of the points and the hours.

Some other issues: your point variable isn't defined either. You need

```
self.point = point
```

in order to have the variable as an actual variable. Also, it might cause some confusion between the point function and the point variable, because of the two being the same name. One or the other, I'd name one as points.

Comment: `self.point() * self.hours` probably. And modify the `point` method accordingly.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre First, thanks for the edit. I completely forgot how to do the modification of it. Secondly, the hours are defined in the first function via `self.hours = hours`, but I don't think the point var is defined, so they might have to do `self.point = point` at the top too. Plus there's probably some issues with the fact that there's the point function and the point variable. Will edit accordingly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what are you trying to do:
You are trying to assign `points * hours` to `QP` which is not possible in python that way, so you have to do it normally like this:

```
`QP = points * hours`
```